# ISO 8859-15 or ISO 8859-1 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, collation, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-15

What collation should be use for ISO 8859-15 or ISO 8859-1  in SQL Server? I have looked around and cannot find references anywhere for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on which language you are going to store. E.g. if you use `SQL_Danish_Pref_Cp1_CI_AS_KI_WI` then `Aarhus` will be sorted after `Xylophone` since `aa` is a spelling of `å`, which is after `x` in the Danish/Norwegian alphabet.

Comment: We will be storing it in English. So, Is there a collation that can be used to validate character sets in ISO 8859-15 or ISO 8859-1 and reject any other characters?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense..  The latin-1 character sets use the entire 256 possible encodings (i.e. there isn't a bit-pattern that represents an "illegal" character).  All the cool kids are using utf-8, but if you're set on latin-1, then SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS_KI_WI might work for you, or one of the Cp437 collations if your English is USian, maybe one of the Cp850 if your English is "Original" ;-)  Seriously though... utf-8 :-)

Comment: We are trying to feed data to a system that only accepts ISO 8859-15 characters. So I'm trying to use collation in SQL server to validate the characters before feeding it. I guess I'll try SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS_KI_WI and see where I get.

Comment: As I said, I think you're misunderstanding what a collation is (it has nothing to do with invalid "characters"). What you are doing is trying to take input bytes and store them as 8859-15 bytes. To do that, you'll need to know which encoding the input bytes are, so that you can decode the bytes to Unicode.  Once you have Unicode text, you'll need to encode it as iso-8859-15 and deal with any Unicode code points ("characters") that cannot be encoded using that encoding. If you haven't read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html yet, it's a good place to start.